# generating vertices for voronoi diagram in d3js

Tags: d3.js, voronoi

In the two examples in d3js website:

[Easy Version](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060366)

[More complicated](http://bl.ocks.org/christophermanning/1734663)

I find some of their code hard to understand. The D3 reference API did not offer in depth explanation. In the easy version, the vertices were generated using Math.random() like so:

```
var vertices = d3.range(100).map(function(d) {
  return [Math.random() * width, Math.random() * height];
});
```

Width and height are the document size. This ensure all vertices are within the scope of the SVG element ( svg tag has width and height attribute set to these values too).

However in the more complicated version, it uses an algorithm to generate the vertices:

```
var vertices = d3.range(numVertices).map(function(d) { return {x: d.x, y: d.y}; })
voronoiVertices = vertices.map(function(o){return [o.x,  o.y, o]})
path = path.data(d3.geom.voronoi(voronoiVertices))
```

When examining the variable `vertices` in console. I found out that it is a two dimensional array. Each sub-array has a length of 3, first and second element are numbers, and the last element is an object which contains a lot more properties like x, y and index and so on.

The resulting Voronoi diagram are very different. Why is that? They are both generated using `d3.geom.voronoi()` and (from what I can hopefully understand) the only differences lies in the object that is passed into it. In the easy example it was simply a two dimensional array with 2 numbers in each sub-array. I cannot seem to see how the two lines in the complicated example works to create such a complex object and append it to the end of each sub-array.

How is it ensured that the veritices are within the bound of the parent SVG element too?

I am really stuck, thank you so much for any help.

Comment: I know d is the D3 datum reference. However I don't even know where does `x, y and o` comes from.

Comment: The second example also uses the force layout, which makes everything more complex. If you're learning D3, the second example is definitely not something you want to start with.

Comment: Yes I realize that however I cannot seem to find a lot of resources out there. I just don't know how to generate the vertices more "evenly" so that each polygons have more or less the same area.

Comment: You might get a better answer if you post a question describing exactly what you want to do and where you're struggling.